# DropDownList Not Visible After Selecting Item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP DropDownList that disappears when an item is selected from it. What is supposed to happen is that another DropDownList is supposed to appear but it doesn't display either.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>KYFB Black Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blackbook.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    <p id="home_title" runat="server">Black Book</p>
    <form id="sign_in_form" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="username_field" runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" /> <br />
        <input id="password_field" runat="server" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" /> <br /> <br />
        <input id="submit_button" runat="server" type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="ajaxFunction();" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <form id="selection_form" runat="server">
        <div id="counties_div" style="display: block; width: 15%; margin: auto;" runat="server">
            <p id="county_list_title" style="color:white;" runat="server">Select a county</p>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="county_list" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="countyChange" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <p id="committee_list_title" style="color:white;" runat="server">Select a committee</p>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="committee_list" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="committeeChange" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: After being asked to provide more of the code, here is all of the C#.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selection_form.Visible = false;
        counties_div.Visible = false;
        submit_button.ServerClick += new EventHandler(this.submitPressed);
    }

    public void displayAlert(String message)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
    }

    public void submitPressed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (username_field.Value == "")
        {

            this.displayAlert("Enter your username");
        }
        else if (password_field.Value == "")
        {

            this.displayAlert("Enter your password");
        }
        else
        {
            // Validate credentials

            String username = username_field.Value;
            String password = password_field.Value;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://membershipwebapp.azurewebsites.net/signin");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var objArray = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(objText);

                // Check if JSON array is empty

                if (objArray.Length == 0)
                {
                    // Display sign in error
                    this.displayAlert("Username or password was incorrect.Try again.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Dictionary<String, dynamic> userDictionary = objArray[0];
                    home_title.InnerHtml = "Welcome, " + userDictionary["FirstName"];

                    // Display black book data

                    sign_in_form.Visible = false;

                    this.getCounties();
                    selection_form.Visible = true;
                    counties_div.Visible = true;
                    committee_list_title.Visible = false;
                    committee_list.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Display error message
                this.displayAlert("An error occurred");
            }

            response.Close();
        }
    }

    public void countyChange(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (county_list.Items[county_list.SelectedIndex].Value != "")
        {
            this.getCommittees();
            committee_list_title.Visible = true;
            committee_list.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    public void getCounties()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://membershipwebapp.azurewebsites.net/counties");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var objArray = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(objText);

            // Check if JSON array is empty

            if (objArray.Length == 0)
            {
                // Display error
                this.displayAlert("Error getting counties");
            }
            else
            {

                county_list.Items.Add("");

                for (int i = 0; i < objArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Get dictionary and add county name to list

                    Dictionary<String, dynamic> countyDictionary = objArray[i];
                    String countyName = countyDictionary["county"];
                    county_list.Items.Add(countyName);

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Display error message
            this.displayAlert("Error getting counties");
        }

        response.Close();
    }

    public void getCommittees()
    {
        String selectedCounty = county_list.Items[county_list.SelectedIndex].Value;
        String url = "https://membershipwebapp.azurewebsites.net/committee/" + selectedCounty;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var objArray = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(objText);

            // Check if JSON array is empty
            this.displayAlert("committee array length: " + objArray.Length);

            if (objArray.Length == 0)
            {
                // Display error
                this.displayAlert("Error getting committees");
            }
            else
            {
                committee_list.Items.Add("");

                for (int i = 0; i < objArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Get dictionary and add county name to list

                    Dictionary<String, dynamic> committeeDictionary = objArray[i];
                    String committeeName = committeeDictionary["committee_name"];
                    committee_list.Items.Add(committeeName);
                    // committeeSelect.Items.Add(committeeName);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Display error message
            this.displayAlert("Error getting committees");
        }

        response.Close();
    }

    public void committeeChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (committee_list.Items[committee_list.SelectedIndex].Value != "")
        {
            // Display committee member info
        }
    }
}
```

**Before selecting a county**
[image]

**After selecting a county**
[image]

Comment: Can you share page_load code and getCommittees code? How are you populating country_list dropdown?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've updated the question to include all the code.